# JS interval not incrementing timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

The button I am listening in on and span element I want to
increment my timer in.

```
      <p class="text2">art</p><br />
      <p class="clocktext">
        <span id="artSession">
          <?php displayTime("art"); ?>
        </span>
      </p><br />
      <button id="artBtn"> record </button><br />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jsfunctions.js"></script>
```

Here is my js functions file im calling from

```
// Beginning of tracker functionality
// variables to begin with
  var interval;
  var hours = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  var displayHrs = 0;
  var displayMins = 0;
  var displaySecs = 0;
  var end, start, totalTime;
  var timerStatus = false;


function sessionTimer() {

  seconds = seconds + 1;

  if(seconds >= 60 ) {
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0;
  } else if ( minutes >= 60 ) {
    hours++;
    minutes = 0;
  }


  // logic to add leading 0
  if( seconds < 10 ) {
    displaySecs = '0' + seconds;
  } else {
    displaySecs = seconds;
  } if( minutes < 10 ) {
    displayMins = '0' + minutes;
  } else {
    displayMins = minutes;
  } if( hours < 10 ) {
    displayHrs = '0' + hours;
  } else {
    displayHrs = hours;
  }

  recordTime = displayHrs + ':' + displayMins + ':' + displaySecs;
  document.getElementById('artSession').innerHTML = recordTime;

} // end of custom timer function




function buttonListening(catBtnId, catBtn, catSession, catSessionId, catagory) {

  $(catBtnId).click(function() {

    if(timerStatus == false) {

      interval = setInterval(sessionTimer(), 1000);
      document.getElementById(catBtn).innerHTML = 'stop';
      timerStatus = true;
      start = new Date();
    }

    else if (timerStatus == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        document.getElementById(catBtn).innerHTML = 'record';

        end = new Date();
        totalTime = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
        timerStatus = false;

        // reset timer values
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        displayHrs = 0;
        displayMins = 0;
        displaySecs = 0;

        // logic to add leading 0
        if( seconds < 10 ) {
          displaySecs = '0' + seconds;
        }  else {
          displaySecs = seconds;
        } if( minutes < 10 ){
          displayMins = '0' + minutes;
        } else {
          displayMins = minutes;
        } if( hours < 10 ){
          displayHrs = '0' + hours;
        } else {
          displayHrs = hours;
        }

        //display formatted time in div
        recordTime = displayHrs + ':' + displayMins + ':' + displaySecs;
        document.getElementById(catSession).innerHTML = recordTime;

        //#sign required    !!include full path
        $(catSessionId).load( 'includes/submit_time.php', {
          postTimeCat: catagory ,
          postTotalTime: totalTime
        });
      }
  });
} // end of custom function storing btn event ---------------------------------------


buttonListening("#artBtn","artBtn","artSession","#artSession","art");



}); // end of js
```

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong. It was all working earlier today... GAHHH this project forsure has empowered me to start using github. Hope one of you guys can help me :C spent like all day smashing face off keyboard to get this thing to work. pet project almost done!

Comment: What do you want it to do, and how is what's it doing now not what you want it to do?

Comment: I want it to keep running my timer function to increment seconds, I get the first second to click and than it stops running

Comment: "I get the first second to click" What does that mean?

Comment: first line in the sessionTimer function is to add 1 to the intital starting value of 0
the recordTime variable displays 00:00:01 and not 00:00:00 so I know for certain it has ran the function once, just not sure how it is able to stop when I have the else if statement to check for the timerStatus == True, indicated the user has clicked and his intentions is to stop the timer on the second click

Answer (score 0):

```
      timeInterval = setInterval(sessionTimer(), 1000);
```

don't need parentheses '()' when passing function name in setInterval()

```
      timeInterval = setInterval(sessionTimer, 1000);
```

hope this saves someone 4hrs